# Наследование по ArrayList

Tags: java

Хочу создать класс, наследуемый по классу ArrayList и переопределить его методы ( допустим добавить в метод .add() счётчик, который будет подсчитывать количество вызываемого метода). Как это сделать просто и без лишних строчек кода?

Comment: Ну ОК, а в чем ваша проблема-то? Покажите свое сложно с лишними строчками хотя бы.

Comment: Моя проблема в том, что если я начну тупо переписывать код метода с исходного класса, то предётся создавать кучу полей и методов. Как обойтись без этого? Можно ли как-то отозваться к методам из наследуемого класса?

Comment: Тогда спросите о том, как оверрайдить методы в Java. `ArrayList`, счетчики и прочее - это ведь лишняя информация.

Comment: Что значит без лишних строчек кода?

Comment: @RomanC судя по комментарию автора, "без копирования исходного кода `ArrayList`".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Примерно вот так:

```
class CustomArrayList<T> extends ArrayList<T> {
    private long addCounter = 0;
    ...
    @Override
    public boolean add(T item) {
        addCounter++;
        return super.add(item);
    }

    public long getAddCounter() {
        return this.addCounter;
    }
}
```

Суть в том, чтобы использовать методы из ArrayList (`super.add()`) и добавить свою кастомную логику.

Comment: Как получить потом значение этого счетчика ?

Comment: @SergeyVlasov ну это уж автор вопроса пусть сам решает - что он будет делать с этим счетчиком...

Comment: @Regent эта аннотация необязательна, но я добавил.

Comment: @SergeyVlasov добавил геттер

Comment: @AndrewBystrov безусловно, но при этом весьма помогает в понимании что переопределено, а что - "своё". И только сейчас заметил: у вас `extend`, а должно быть `extends`.